# Does there always exist a polynomial of max degree n that maps between two sets of size n?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, polynomials

Given a set $A = \{a_1, a_2, ... , a_n\}$
And a set $B = \{b_1, b_2, ..., b_n\}$ where $n > 0$ (neither $A$ nor $B$ are $\emptyset$) and $a_1 \ne a_2 \ne ... \ne a_n$
With no further restrictions on $B$ does there always exist a polynomial function, $P$, with $order \le n $ such that $P(a_n)=b_n$?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use Lagrange interpolation:

$P=\sum_{i=1,..,n} b_i{{(X-a_1)..(X-a_{i-1})(X-a_{i+1})..(X-a_n)}\over{(a_i-a_1)..(a_i-a_{i-1})(a_i-a_{i+1})..(a_i-a_n)}}$

Comment: Thanks! This is really cool!